# Using C to Call a function inside a Python file

Tags: python, c

I'm using the following code to call a script called multiple inside a python file called also multiple.py:

```
#include <Python2.7/Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc;
    PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
    int i;

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: call pythonfile funcname [args]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    Py_Initialize();
    pName = PyString_FromString("multiply");

    Py_DECREF(pName);

    if (pModule != NULL) {
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, argv[2]);

        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
            pArgs = PyTuple_New(argc - 3);
            for (i = 0; i < argc - 3; ++i) {
                pValue = PyInt_FromLong(atoi(argv[i + 3]));
                if (!pValue) {
                    Py_DECREF(pArgs);
                    Py_DECREF(pModule);
                    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, i, pValue);
            }
            pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
            Py_DECREF(pArgs);
            if (pValue != NULL) {
                printf("Result of call: %ld\n", PyInt_AsLong(pValue));
                Py_DECREF(pValue);
            }
            else {
                Py_DECREF(pFunc);
                Py_DECREF(pModule);
                PyErr_Print();
                fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (PyErr_Occurred())
                PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);
        }
        Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
    }
    else {
        PyErr_Print();
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

This is given the following error:

```
Failed to load "multiply.py"
```

And I can't figure it out what I'm doing wrongly.

The structure:

```
| dist/
| - main.out
| src/
| - main.c
| multiple.py
```

Inside the multiple.py:

```
def multiply(a, b):
    print "Will compute", a, "times", b
    c = 0
    for i in range(0, a):
        c = c + b
    return c
```

And the command line:

```
gcc src/main.c -framework Python -o dist/main.out && ./dist/main.out multiply.py 32
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see you initializing `pModule` anywhere. Looks like you forgot to import module.

Comment: And most probably your compiler gives you a warning about using uninitialized variables. You should always compile with `-Wall` and probably `-Wextra`. And ensure no warnings show up.

Comment: Check again, the pModule is being initialized in the 5 line, also, this is from the official documentation.

Comment: multiple.py or multiply.py? The directory listing says one, your supposed command line another. If there is a true mismatch, well...

Comment: @Celo> it is not. It is declared, but not initialized: you don't give it a value.